# $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx=n \lambda(B^n) \int_0^\infty g(r)r^{n-1}dr$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $g: \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x)=g(|x|)$.

I already showed that $f$ is integrable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ iff $r \mapsto r^{n-1} g(r)$ is integrable in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

How do I show that
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)dx=n \lambda(B^n) \int_0^\infty g(r)r^{n-1}dr$ as well? ($B^n$ is the unit ball)

Comment: See 'polar coordinartes in$\mathbb R^{n}$'  in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I may be misremembering, but I don't think Rudin talks about polar coordinates. An alternative reference is Folland's *Real Analysis*, page 77 of the second edition.

Comment: @Reveillark 'Polar coordinates' is even mentioned in the index of the book. In my edition  there is a clear decription of Polar coordinates in Exercise 6 of Chapter 8.